# HPLIP software installation fails during 'make' command

Tags: software-installation, hplip

Below is the last screen output up to the failure:

```
Distro set to: Ubuntu 16.04

Initializing. Please wait...


SECURITY PACKAGES
-----------------
AppArmor is installed. 
AppArmor protects the application from external intrusion attempts making the application secure

Would you like to have this installer install the hplip specific policy/profile (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ? y


RUNNING PRE-INSTALL COMMANDS
----------------------------
OK


RUNNING HPLIP LIBS REMOVE COMMANDS
----------------------------------
None
OK


RUNNING SCANJET DEPENDENCY COMMANDS
-----------------------------------
sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-pip (Scanjet-depend step 1)
sudo pip install --upgrade pip (Scanjet-depend step 2)
sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libleptonica-dev (Scanjet-depend step 3)
sudo apt-get install --assume-yes tesseract-ocr (Scanjet-depend step 4)
sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libtesseract-dev (Scanjet-depend step 5)
sudo -H pip install tesserocr (Scanjet-depend step 6)
sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libzbar-dev (Scanjet-depend step 7)
sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-zbar (Scanjet-depend step 8)
sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-opencv (Scanjet-depend step 9)
sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-pypdf2 (Scanjet-depend step 10)
sudo -H pip install imutils (Scanjet-depend step 11)
sudo -H pip install pypdfocr (Scanjet-depend step 12)
sudo -H pip install scikit-image (Scanjet-depend step 13)
sudo -H pip install scipy (Scanjet-depend step 14)
OK


PRE-BUILD COMMANDS
------------------
OK


BUILD AND INSTALL
-----------------
Running './configure --with-hpppddir=/usr/share/ppd/HP --libdir=/usr/lib --prefix=/usr --enable-qt4 --disable-qt5 --enable-doc-build --disable-cups-ppd-install --disable-foomatic-drv-install --disable-libusb01_build --disable-foomatic-ppd-install --disable-hpijs-install --disable-class-driver --disable-udev_sysfs_rules --disable-policykit --enable-cups-drv-install --enable-hpcups-install --enable-network-build --enable-dbus-build --enable-scan-build --enable-fax-build --enable-apparmor_build'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Command completed successfully.

Running 'make clean'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
Command completed successfully.

Running 'make'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: 'make' command failed with status code 2
```

Comment: Why not install HPLIP from the Ubuntu repos? Or download it from https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip?

Comment: Thank you both fro responding! Heynnema, I'm downloading the HPLIP sw from the HPLIP site as you suggested. N0rbert, I followed your instructions and ran sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui. That command completed with no errors, but where do I go from there, how do I actually get the printer setup? I'm a newbie to linux, so it's not apparent to me what next steps should be.

Comment: I was able to run the make command from within the hplip folder, here's the last part of the output..........
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:5180: recipe for target 'libhpdiscovery.la' failed
make: *** [libhpdiscovery.la] Error 1

Comment: Simply run `hp-setup` .